# Invalid characters in String

Tags: java, arrays, string, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying transform a String input that has hyphens and underscores into camel case.

Example:

```
the-stealth-warrior
```

should become

```
theStealthWarrior
```

I thought I understood completely the problem until I ran into some weird invalid output issues when I run the code.

My code:

```java
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(toCamelCase("the-stealth-warrior"));
    }

    public static String toCamelCase(String s) {
        int sLength = s.length();

        char[] camelCaseWord = new char[sLength];
        int camelCaseIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < sLength; i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == '-' || s.charAt(i) == '_') {
                char upper = Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i + 1));
                camelCaseWord[camelCaseIndex] = upper;
                camelCaseIndex++;
                i++;
            } else {
                camelCaseWord[i] = s.charAt(i);
                camelCaseIndex++;
            }
        }
        return new String(camelCaseWord);
    }
}
```

My output:

```
theS tealtW  arrior
```

Does anyone know what could be the issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change to

```
camelCaseWord[camelCaseIndex] = s.charAt(i);
```

Also you should check this

```
char upper = Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i + 1));
```

to make sure that it does not exceed then bounds of the String in the case where hyphen or underbar is at the end of the String

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this (I think it is a little less complicated):

```
   private static void covertToCamelCase(String s) {
    String camelCaseString = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if(s.charAt(i) == '_' || s.charAt(i) == '-'){
            
            // if  hyphen or underscore is at the beggining
            if(i == 0) {
                camelCaseString += s.toLowerCase().charAt(i+1);
            }  // if  hyphen or underscore is at the end
            else if(i != s.length()-1) {
                camelCaseString += s.toUpperCase().charAt(i + 1);
            }

            i++;
        }else{
            camelCaseString += s.charAt(i);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(camelCaseString);
}
```

When you run the code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    covertToCamelCase("test_test");
    covertToCamelCase("some-new-string-word");
    covertToCamelCase("hyphen-at-end-");
    covertToCamelCase("-hyphen-at-beginning-");
}
```

The output will be:

```
testTest
someNewStringWord
hyphenAtEnd
hyphenAtBeginning
```

Comment: thank you! I see your logic and it makes sense. Still not 100% sure why mine was wrong.

Comment: The problem is in the else statement. Like Scary Wombat wrote, you should change camelCaseWord[i] = s.charAt(i); to camelCaseWord[camelCaseIndex] = s.charAt(i);